# How to select grand-grand child (Like 5th OR 6th grand child) element using xpath which has class name only

Tags: java, xpath, grandchild

I am trying to select a 5th or 6th grand child which do not have any other attributes other than class name. Please check below example DOM.

```
<div id="abc abc abc">
  <a>
    <a>
      <a>
        <a>
          <a>
</div>
```

Can I find last **Fifth a** using xpath?? Don't want to use something like //div/a/a/a/a/a

Answer (score 2):

The inside a predicate, the [`position()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-position) fuction works against the locator step axis. That is called [proximity position](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-proximity-position). So this XPath expression:

```
//div[@id='abc abc abc']/descendant::a[5]
```

Meaning:

> Select the fifth `a` element descendant of such `div` element

That expression with this wellformed input:

```
<div id="abc abc abc"> 
  <a> 
    <a> 
      <a> 
        <a> 
          <a id="target"/> 
        </a> 
      </a> 
    </a> 
  </a> 
</div>
```

Selects:

```
<a id="target"/>
```

Test in [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/2da5fa1bd3e1cef3ed4566168c325e17)